# Measure vertical distance of binarized image (Open CV) C++

Tags: c++, opencv

So this should be straight forward but I a not very familiar with OpenCV.

Can someone suggest a method to measure the distance in pixels (red line) as shown in the image below? Preferably it had some options like width of measurement (as demonstrated at the end and begining of the red line) or something of sorts. This kind of measurement is very common in software like ImageJ, I can imagine it should be somewhat trivial to do it in OpenCV.

I would like to take several samples accros the image width as well.

[image: binarized image]

Greets

I am using openCV and learning about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your task is quite simple.

1. optional [smoothing](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html) (Gauss filter) - you have to experiment with your data to see if it helps
2. edge detection (will transform image to lines representing edges) - for example [cv::Canny](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d5c/tutorial_canny_detector.html)
3. [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to detect lines - [openCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html).
4. Find two maximum values (longest lines) in Hough transform
5. you will have two questions of straight lines, then you can use this information to calculate distance between them

Note that whit this approach image doesn't have to be straight. You will have line equations which you have to manipulate in smart way. If those two lines are parallel this there is simple formula to get distance between them. If they are not perfectly parallel then you have to take this int account and use information about image area to get average distance.

Comment: Thanks this was very useful. I ended up using this approach to find some lines then I get the midpoint  of line and perpendicular slope to get perpendicular line function. Then iterate along this function until black pixels are found again.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to find the width of the channel would be the following:

```
distance = []
h = img.shape[0]
for j in range(img.shape[1]):
    line_top = 0
    line_bottom = img.shape[0]
    found_top = False
    found_bottom = False
    for i in range(h):
        if img[i,j,0] > 0 and not found_top:
            line_top = i
            found_top = True
        if img[h-i-1,j,0] > 0 and not found_bottom:
            line_bottom = h-i
            found_bottom = True
        if found_top and found_bottom:
            distance.append(line_bottom-line_top)
            break
```

But this would cause the distance to take into acount the very small white speckles.

To solve this there are several options:

1. Preprocess the image using `opencv` `morphological transformation`.
2. Preprocess the image using `opencv` `gaussian filter` or similar.
3. Update the code to use a larger window.

Another solution would be to apply `opencv's findContours`.

Comment: are you aware that this is question about OpenCV?

Comment: Added `opencv` three times for @Marek R.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up using this suggestion partially in combination with the anser from Marek, see comment in his answer.